# Developing on Arnova 9 G3 - not visible via 'adb devices'

Tags: android

I have the new Arnova 9 G3 running Android 4.0.3, just bought on 23rd April from Maplin. I'm trying to start development on my Mac running OS X 10.7. But I can't get it to show up in Eclipse or via the 'adb' tool that comes with the Android Mac SDK.

I have added 0x0e79 to the ~/.android/adb_usb.ini file.

When I plug in the Arnova 9 G3 and type 'adb devices', nothing is listed. I have USB debugging enabled.

When I plug in my Galaxy Nexus running Android 4.0.2 in, and type 'adb devices' at the console, I see the device listed.

Any ideas what I need to do?

Comment: after you add usb ids to that file you may need to do `adb kill-server` + `adb start-server`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - that doesn't help unfortunately.