# Android tablet Arnova Arnova 10b g3 not showing in adb devices mac

Tags: android, macos

I am encountering the same problem as this [Developing on Arnova 9 G3 - not visible via 'adb devices'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307470/developing-on-arnova-9-g3-not-visible-via-adb-devices). 
I am working on MAC OSX LION

My tablet is an ARNOVA 10b G3. I am trying to make it recognized by the adb-devices to debug some application on it. 
The tablet is recognized to transfert file and the debugging option is activated on tablet side.

I also checked this link http://www.archos.com/support/support_tech/updates_adb.html?country=in&lang=en
and made add the file as they specified.

The tablet is never showing in the Devices chooser form eclipse and neither showing when I use the adb -devices command

I have no Idea of what else I can do.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Few things you could try:

    On your device go to Settings > Storage > USB Computer Connection > Select Camera(PTP) mode.

    Also if you are using eclipse change the Base local debugger port to something like 8601. Increase the ADB connection time. Also put a check in box that says, Use ABDHOST.

Comment: Thnak for the advices there is a device now showing in the device chooser. The device id is 123456789ABCDEF and the device is offline. I tried the commands adb kill-server adb start-server but the device is still offline any idea about that ? Thanks

Comment: Are you looking in the DDMS perspective in eclipse?

Comment: Yes I do. Also when I the device chooser pop up appear the device appear offline. I tryed with several USB wire it not working. But when I plug the device I get this messages in the console.  Adb rejected command to check status of view server on device 
Adb rejected command to start view server on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2012-09-05 13:16:51 - hierarchyviewer]Adb rejected command to start view server on device 0123456789ABCDEF
[2012-09-05 13:16:51 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to debug device 0123456789ABCDEF  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is opening up the  android_winusb.inf file and adding a few lines relevant to your device in that file, then restarting computer.

Comment: I still can not debug on my tablet from mac. I have tested all the solution suggested. Does anybody has managed to make such table work for debugging purpose. I sent a message to Arnova but got no answer...

Comment: I have the same problem, I cannot seem to fix it. I will try it on my Windows machine tonight and will let you know tomorrow.

Comment: Im having problems with the tablet altogether. It doesn't turn on anymore (and I only used it once) If I fix this issue I will try the above.