# adb can not recognize chinese tablet on mac os x

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, ddms

adb cant recognize a tablet via usb connection.
env: mac os x 10.8.3
     eclipse juno
tablet: model number: rk30sdk
        android ver.: 4.1.1

- another chinese tablet is recognized so this may not be an issue with the mac
- also rk30sdk tablet is recognized and rooted with a windows machine so i think the tablet and usb cable is ok.

what i have tried so far:
1. usb debugging is enabled on tablet
2. power cycle both tablet and mac with usb cable connected and disconnected
3. base local debugger and adbhost suggestions as mentioned here: [Android tablet Arnova Arnova 10b g3 not showing in adb devices mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267967/android-tablet-arnova-arnova-10b-g3-not-showing-in-adb-devices-mac)
4. ./adb kill-server, start-server, and devices did not work
4. reinstalled andoid sdk and tools
5. reinstalled eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not able to connect to the device with Mac or Ubuntu or Windows with USB cable. But I have managed to connect via wifi using an app called Wifi ADB Pro. Just installed it and from Mac terminal "adb connect ". But for this app you must have super user rights :(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with a Ployer Momo7, would not be recognized at all, under Windows AND Mac OS X. Found [a custom modded firmware](http://www.rockchipfirmware.com/node/146), which works fine and allows root access. No problems at all after this with the above tip, under Mac OS X 10.9. Was also able to connect via USB under Windows 7 after this, using [the Universal ADB (Android Debug Bridge) Driver for Windows](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [lsusb](https://github.com/jlhonora/lsusb)
2. run `lsusb`

> Bus 026 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corporation Hub
>
> Bus 026 Device 004: ID 2717:9039 2717 MI 2  Serial: 4d8a2b9a
>
> Bus 026 Device 003: ID 05ac:8511 Apple Inc. FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)  Serial: CC2D950092DTL5F0
>
> Bus 029 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corporation Hub
>
> Bus 029 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple Inc. iPhone  Serial: 
>   950706f41df8cc971de167af1350e0a4e88aaa7f
>
> Bus 029 Device 003: ID 0424:2412 SMSC Hub
>
> Bus 029 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BRCM20702 Hub
>
> Bus 029 Device 007: ID 05ac:828b Apple Inc. Bluetooth USB Host Controller
>
> Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>
> Bus 026 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
>
> Bus 029 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

3. My connected device is MI 2, add that device id to .ini

   `echo "0x2717" >>~/.android/adb_usb.ini`
4. restart adb